# Adding <option> selected attribute to php contact form with validation

Tags: php, jquery

I need a little help creating a php code for simple contact form with validation. So far it works as predicted but I couldn`t make to add 2  selected attribute to work properly.

HTML code

```
<form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm"  novalidate>
       <legend>Contact me</legend>
     <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Full Name" id="name" required
                   data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
          <p class="help-block"></p>
       </div>
         </div>     
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" 
                        id="email" required
                   data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
    </div>
    </div>  

           <div class="control-group">
             <div class="controls">
             <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Message" id="message" required
           data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" minlength="5" 
                   data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" 
                    maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
    </div>
           </div>        
     <div id="success"> </div> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button><br />
      </form>
```

Js code

```
/*
  Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
   example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
  */
$(function() {

 $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
     preventSubmit: true,
     submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // something to have when submit produces an error ?
      // Not decided if I need it yet
     },
     submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
       // get values from FORM
       var name = $("input#name").val();  
       var email = $("input#email").val(); 
       var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
           // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
       firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
         }        
     $.ajax({
                url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
                cache: false,
                success: function() {  
                // Success message
                   $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                   $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append( "</button>");
                  $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');

          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
          },
       error: function() {      
        // Fail message
         $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                 .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='mailto:me@example.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com'>me@example.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
        //clear all fields
        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
           })
         },
         filter: function() {
                   return $(this).is(":visible");
         },
       });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).tab("show");
        });
  });


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */ 
$('#name').focus(function() {
     $('#success').html('');
  });
```

And finally the PHP as following

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'receipt@gmail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. Here are the details:\n \n".
                  "Name: $name \n".
                  "Email: $email_address \n".
                  "Message: \n \n $message";
$headers = "From: contacts@myprogrammingblog.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, and a vague question. You say you want to add a `<option>`, but I don't see a `<select>` tag anywhere in your code. Also, when do you want to add it? This question is unclear in its current format

Answer (score 0):

A drop-down menu is displayed like this in HTML:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="" selected style="display:none;">-- Choose from this list --</option>
    <option value="value1">This is value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">This is value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">This is value 3</option>
</select>
```

And to get which value was selected in PHP, you run this POST:

```
$dropdown= $_POST["dropdown"];
```

`$dropdown` in PHP will return the value in the HTML form (so either "value1", value2" or "value3" in this case).

Comment: I tried this way. Still not getting selected value in delivered message. Would be useful I send you source files?

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $dropdown;` after getting the `$_POST`?